# Heroku: Processes have temporarily been disabled

Tags: heroku

When running `heroku ps` or `heroku run {anything}` I get the error:

!    Processes have temporarily been disabled.

Attempting to run from collaborator or owner results in same issue. I have a trouble-ticket in with Heroku with no response, yet. Their status app says everything is fine right now. I can console into other apps in my account, just not this one.

How to fix?

Answer (score 1):

From heroku: "This was caused by an lock placed on your application during the shared database migration some time ago; in the vast majority of cases, this lock was automatically removed when the migration finished, but it appears a small handful of applications did not get this flag removed."